Memory leak in FastAPI WebSocket chat application - background task management with asyncio
I am running a FastAPI + WebSocket project for a customer support chat, and I've been facing a memory leak issue that I haven’t been able to fully resolve.
When a client connects to the server, two infinite loops are defined.
The first loop reads the messages sent by the connected client and handles business logic:
@router.websocket("/{hashconnection}")
@inject
async def websocket_endpoint(
    websocket: WebSocket,
    hashconnection: str,
    authorization: Optional[str] = None,
    ....injected dependencies....
):
    print("Opening connection:", hashconnection, websocket.client.host)
    await websocket_connection_service.on_connect(hashconnection, websocket)
    try:
        while True:
            try:
                await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
                payload_message = json.loads(await websocket.receive_text())
                message_type = payload_message.get("type")
                message_data = payload_message.get("data")
                # ...handle business logic...
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        await websocket_connection_service.on_disconnect(hashconnection, websocket)
        print("DISCONNECTED:", hashconnection, websocket.client.host)
        return

The second loop listens to the Redis broker to check for new messages that need to be delivered to the connected client:
class WebsocketConnectionService:
    def __init__(
        self,
        pubsub_manager: RedisPubSubAdapter,
        connection_repository: IConnectionRepository,
    ):
        self.pubsub_client = pubsub_manager
        self.connection_repository = connection_repository
        self.connections: dict = {}
        self.pubsub_tasks = {}

    async def on_connect(self, hashconnection: str, websocket: WebSocket):
        await websocket.accept()

        if hashconnection in self.connections:
            self.connections[hashconnection].append(websocket)
        else:
            self.connections[hashconnection] = [websocket]
            self.pubsub_tasks[hashconnection] = asyncio.create_task(self._pubsub_data_reader(hashconnection))

    async def drop_async_task(self, hashconnection: str) -> None:
        if hashconnection in self.pubsub_tasks:
            self.pubsub_tasks[hashconnection].cancel()
            try:
                await self.pubsub_tasks[hashconnection]
            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                pass
            del self.pubsub_tasks[hashconnection]
            
    async def on_disconnect(self, hashconnection: str, websocket: WebSocket):
        await self.drop_async_task(hashconnection)

        connection_cache = await self.connection_repository.get(hashconnection)
        if not connection_cache:
            return

        # Additional business logic when disconnecting...
        await self.connection_repository.update(hashconnection, connection_cache)
        await self.remove_user_from_room(hashconnection, websocket)

    async def _pubsub_data_reader(self, hashconnection: str):
        conn = await self.pubsub_client.redis_connection.get_master_connection()
        pubsub = conn.pubsub()
        await pubsub.subscribe(hashconnection)

        while True:
            try:
                await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
                message = await pubsub.get_message(ignore_subscribe_messages=True)
            except Exception:
                print(traceback.print_exc())
                return

            if message is not None:
                hashconnection = message["channel"].decode("utf-8")
                if hashconnection not in self.connections:
                    continue

                all_sockets = self.connections[hashconnection]
                if await self.pubsub_client.check_if_hashconnection_is_subscribed(hashconnection):
                    data = message["data"].decode("utf-8")
                    for socket in all_sockets:
                        try:
                            await socket.send_text(data)
                        except Exception:
                            await self.remove_user_from_room(hashconnection, self.connections[hashconnection][0])

I suspect that the issue may lie in the background task

asyncio.create_task(self._pubsub_data_reader(hashconnection))

. When a client disconnects, it triggers the WebSocket router exception, and I’ve implemented a mechanism to manage these background tasks. I store the task reference in a class variable and attempt to stop it when the client goes through the on_disconnect flow. While this has reduced the memory leak, it hasn’t solved it completely.
Here is a memory usage graph for this service. The memory is never released, unless we redeploy the instances to reset them.

Questions:
Could this issue be related to improper cleanup of the WebSocket connection or background tasks?
Is there a better way to ensure that tasks created with asyncio.create_task() are properly terminated when a client disconnects?
What could I be missing in terms of properly handling WebSocket disconnects to avoid memory leaks?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
